# Styled Components not displaying in Chrome

Tags: reactjs, typescript, webpack, babeljs, styled-components

I have created a react app that is using typescript, webpack and babel. I decided to incorporate styled-components for styling. When using my GlobalStyles component the app does not display in chrome browser but when i remove GlobalStyles the app displays. I inspect my app in Chrome and can see the styles from GlobalStyles being applied but again the app does not display. There are no error messages in console log and terminal states compiled successfully.

Has anyone encountered this problem and have a possible solution?

webpack.config.js

```
const path = require('path')
require("babel-polyfill")
const rules = [
    {
        test: /\.tsx?$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: ['babel-loader','awesome-typescript-loader']
    },
    {
        test: /\.(png|gif|svg)$/,
        loader: ['file-loader', 'url-loader']
    },
    {
        test: /\.css$/,
        loader: ['style-loader', 'css-loader']
    }
]

module.exports = {
    target: 'web',
    mode: 'development',
    entry: ['babel-polyfill', './src/index.tsx'],
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
        filename: 'bundle.js'
    },
    module: { rules },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.ts', '.tsx', '.js']
    },
    devServer: {
        contentBase: './public',
        port: 5000
    }
}
```

.babelrc

```
{
  "presets": ["@babel/preset-env", "@babel/preset-react", "@babel/preset-typescript"],
  "plugins": ["babel-plugin-styled-components","transform-regenerator"]
}
```

globalStyles.js

```
import { createGlobalStyle } from "styled-components";

export const GlobalStyles = createGlobalStyle`
    html {
        -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
        box-sizing: content-box;
    }
    *, *:before, *:after {
        -webkit-box-sizing: inherit;
        box-sizing: inherit;
    }

    body {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', 'Roboto', 'Oxygen',
         'Ubuntu', 'Cantarell', 'Fira Sans', 'Droid Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
         -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
         -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
    }
`;
```

index.tsx

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import App from "./App";
import { GlobalStyles } from "../styles/globalStyles.js";

import { StoreProvider } from "./Store";

const root = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <StoreProvider>
      <GlobalStyles>
        <App />
      </GlobalStyles>
    </StoreProvider>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  root
);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put your Global style in this way , that is, don't put any components inside it

```
const root = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <StoreProvider>
      <GlobalStyles />
      <App />
    </StoreProvider>
  </React.StrictMode>
  root
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Anything take a look at this example taken from the library documentation
https://styled-components.com/docs/api

```
import { createGlobalStyle } from 'styled-components'

const GlobalStyle = createGlobalStyle`
  body {
    color: ${props => (props.whiteColor ? 'white' : 'black')};
  }
`

// later in your app

<React.Fragment>
  <GlobalStyle whiteColor />
  <Navigation /> {/* example of other top-level stuff */}
</React.Fragment>
```